# How to include a math equation as a footnote or source note in a gt table

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, quarto, gt

I'm working in a Quarto html document. I would like to include a footnote or a source note in a gt table, rendered as html, that includes a math equation. The idea is that I would like this to serve as a calculation note clarifying how calculations were performed.

I cannot get the source note to display a math equation. Latex appears not to render correctly. I would like the footnote to display as an actual math equation fraction.

```
gtcars_table  = gtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(mfr, model, msrp) %>% 
  dplyr::slice(1:5) %>% 
  gt()  

gtcars_table %>% 
  tab_source_note(source_note = md("(A - B) / C"))
```

[Image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TpIV.png)

I am able to add an equation using inline latex as such, but that does not appear as proper spacing in relation to the table like a footnote would:

```
$\frac{{\text{A} - \text{B}}}{{\text{B}}}$
```